# Retrieve information of objects with checked check-box in Struts

Tags: jsp, struts2

For example, I have the following table:

```
<s:form action="assign_manager">
    <s:hidden name="id" value="id" />
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Check box</th>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="accounts">
        <tr>
            <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="surname" /></td>
            <td><s:checkbox name="check" /></td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
    </table>
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

I want to create a List in my action class which will store the ids of the checked accounts. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `fieldValue` attribute of `<s:checkbox>` tag.

Comment: What are you iterating, where are that ids that you want to store?